# How to convert Unit8List to Files in flutter

Tags: opencv, flutter

I have used opencv to enhance the image in flutter which returns a Unit8List as a dynamic result i have used to display the image.

```
Image newImage =  Image.memory(res);
```

How to convert that image it to file, or how to write Unit8List as a file. I have tried this but its printing  ���� as the file path

```
 File imageNeww = File.fromRawPath(res);
 print(imageNeww.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the file class

```
File f = File('desired/path/to/file.png');
await f.writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

here bytes are your Uint8List

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'storage/emulated/0/DigiScan/Pic1.jpg' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Comment: the error tells you what exactly you must do!! get the needed permission, in your case its storage

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: I have added these two lines in AndroidManifest.xml file but still it is giving same error

Comment: that just tells the os and play store that your app uses those permissions, you have to explicitly ask for permissions, the visual permission pop ups!!??..use any flutter library for that